# Make Apache Ant copy path entries differently, depending on whether the entry is a file or a directory

Tags: java, ant

In pure Apache Ant, given a path like below, which contains a mix of directories and files:

```xml
<path id="my.path">
  <pathelement path="foo/some-directory:resource/license/license.txt:some-other-directory:resource/readme.txt" />
</path>
```

and a directory structure like this:

```
project
+- foo
|  +- some-directory
|     +- foo.txt
|     +- bar.txt
+- resource
|  +- license
|  |  +- license.txt
|  +- readme.txt
+- some-other-directory
   +- foobar.txt
```

how does one copy files and directories in a generic way, so that the end result for this example looks like so:

```
target
+- some-directory
|  +- foo.txt
|  +- bar.txt
+- license.txt
+- readme.txt
+- some-other-directory
   +- foobar.txt
```

Basically, if a path entry is a directory, copy the directory and its contents, if a path entry is a file, copy only that file.

For clarity, the path in the XML snippet above contains these as separate entries:

- `foo/some-directory`
- `resource/license/license.txt`
- `some-other-directory`
- `resource/readme.txt`

Comment: foo/some-directory mapped to some-directory, but some-other-directory mapped to itself.  Are those special cases, or is the rule "map to the just the last subdirectory of the path", e.g. a/b/c maps to c, e/f/g/h maps to h?

Comment: @martinclayton, correct, the rule is "map to last directory of the path", for directory paths.

Comment: I ended up implementing this via `taskdef` and a Java class. Still interested in a pure Ant solution however.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have time yet to look at it.  I think it can be done with two tasks using selectors, one for the directories and one for files.